# How to download html source using RoboSpice?

Tags: android, html, robospice

I want to download the html from a static blog page so I can get the relevant data and use it. For asynchronous procedures I'm using [robospice library](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice).

Thing is, using SimpleTextRequest I only get the first line of the html, namely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Which request should I use to download the whole html source? I've failed to find anything similar in samples. And googling "robospice" mostly leads to their sourcecode, it seems there's little in terms of tutorials for this library.

UPDATE: Inspiredby the first answer, I have created this custom spicerequest:

```
 public class HtmlRequest extends SpiceRequest<String> {

    private static String reqUrl;

    public HtmlRequest(String url) {
        super(String.class);
        reqUrl = url;
        aLog.d("HtmlRequest.HtmlRequest url : " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        String html = "";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(reqUrl);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        aLog.d("HtmlRequest.loadDataFromNetwork statusCode : " + statusCode);
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            /*
             * Si todo fue ok, montamos la String con el HTML
             */
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                aLog.d("HtmlRequest.loadDataFromNetwork line : " + line);
                builder.append(line);
            }
            html = builder.toString();
            aLog.d("HtmlRequest.loadDataFromNetwork html : " + html);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return html;
    }

}
```

Then, on my Activity I have

```
spiceManager.execute(htmlRequest, "text", DurationInMillis.NEVER, new StaticItemRequestListener());
```

And yet I get none of the logs I set on my custom request, besides the one in the constructor method.

Thing is: while my htmlRequest apparently isn't being executed, I still get the xml header above. I must be doing something so wrong and yet I am so unable to see it...

Answer (score 2):

It's strange you are getting the header of a xml file instead html.
Try asking to your server the html version:

```
public class ExampleRequest extends SpiceRequest<String> {

    public ExampleRequest() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

        String url = "your website url";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");       
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");            
        String result = IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        urlConnection.disconnect();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried it out on this url http://www.sevilladirecto.com/telefonos-de-interes/ and I get the same result
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: I would try adding some other headers. Try checking which headers are sent from your browser when you visit that page and add them to the request.

Comment: I found the issue: I used on the same activity 2 different requests with the same spicemanager. The second one would always give me that funny header for result. If I only launch one request it goes ok.

Comment: really strange behavior. If you found a bug, please take time to fill a proper issue with a snipper of code to reproduce the problem, or better, a failing test.